# Split date range into months ranges in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For example I have a start and end date like this:

Input:

```
$startDate = 2022-01-03
$endDate = 2022-03-03
```

My desired output is:

```
[0] => Array
         (
             [start] => 2022-01-03
             [end] => 2022-01-31
         )

[1] => Array
         (
             [start] => 2022-02-01
             [end] => 2022-02-28
         )
[2] => Array
         (
             [start] => 2022-03-01
             [end] => 2022-03-03
         )
```

Comment: And what’s your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work...

```
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-01-03')->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-03-03')->format('Y-m-d');
$period = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, '1 month', $endDate);


$p = array();

foreach ($period as $date) {

    $p[] = (object)[
      "start"=> ($date->firstOfMonth()->gt($startDate)) ? $date->firstOfMonth()->toDateString(): $startDate, 
      "end"=> ($date->lastOfMonth()->lt($endDate)) ? $date->lastOfMonth()->toDateString() : $endDate
      ];
      
}

print_r($p);
```